# Iterate from one data frame to another, error

Tags: r

I want to fill the NA in df with the values in data frame dat and iterate over columns, but it doesn't work, why? Or is there a better solution?

```
id <- factor(rep(letters[1:2], each=5))
A <- c(1,2,NA,6,8,9,0,6,7,9)
B <- c(5,6,1,9,8,1,NA,9,7,4)
C <- c(2,3,5,NA,NA,2,7,6,4,6)
D <- c(6,5,8,3,2,9,NA,2,6,8)
df <- data.frame(id, A, B,C,D) 
df

   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a NA  1  5  8
4   a  6  9 NA  3
5   a  8  8 NA  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 NA  7 NA
8   b  6  9  6  2
9   b  7  7  4  6
10  b  9  4  6  8

dat <- data.frame(col=c("A","B","C","D"), value=c(23,45,26,89))
dat

 col value
1   A    23
2   B    45
3   C    26
4   D    89

test <- function(i){
  df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] <- dat$value[dat$col==i]
  return(df)
}
df <-df[,-1]

for(i in colnames(df)){
  df[[i]] <- test(i)
}
df #DOESN'T WORK
```

Should look like:

```
 df
   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a 23  1  5  8
4   a  6  9 26  3
5   a  8  8 26  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 45  7 89
8   b  6  9  6  2
9   b  7  7  4  6
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

Comment: `test` returns the *whole data frame*, but you assign the result of `test` to a single column. I think it will work if you make `test` `return(df[i])`

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas I have another question:)  But when I type  str(df) I get the code below. It look different from the 'normal str(df). something happended with the data and I think this complicated things I'm trying to do later. 
'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ A:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ A: num  1 2 23 6 8 9 0 6 7 9
 $ B:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ B: num  5 6 1 9 8 1 45 9 7 4
 $ C:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ C: num  2 3 5 26 26 2 7 6 4 6
 $ D:'data.frame': 10 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ D: num  6 5 8 3 2 9 89 2 6 8

Comment: how it looks as 'usual': 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ id: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
 $ A : num  1 2 23 6 8 9 0 6 7 9
 $ B : num  5 6 1 9 8 1 45 9 7 4
 $ C : num  2 3 5 26 26 2 7 6 4 6
 $ D : num  6 5 8 3 2 9 NA 2 6 8

Comment: That weird structure is what happens when you assign a data frame to a column of a data frame. My mistake above, I forgot the comma. Should have been `return(df[, i])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `replace_na` function from `tidyr` should do what you want.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  replace_na(list(
    "A" = 23,
    "B" = 45, 
    "C" = 26,
    "D" = 89
  ))
```